# How to make pie chart in a row

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Can someone help me put the pie charts from chart.js in one row? I tried this, but it doesnt work.

`

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="chart-container" style="position: right; height:40vh; width:40vw">
          <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="chart-container" style="position: left; height:40vh; width:40vw">
          <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

`

Comment: You need to provide enough code to produce a minimum reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `class="row"` probably makes sure that the rows are placed beneath eachother. You should also try using `float: ...` instead of `position: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>
     <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).